# how to fetch all the links starting with http://plus

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a pregmatch with the following search :

```
   $regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
```

now how can I reformat this to look for something like :

```
href="http://plus
```

I dont want the entire thing to be changed , just that part for the href.

Thanks

Comment: As usual... don't use regex for parseing html. You'll just shoot yourself in the foot at some point. Use DOM and XPath instead: `//a[starts-with(@href,'http://plus')]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)(http:\/\/plus[^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";`